# tortoisesvn is out of date you have to update your working copy first

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn, visualsvn-server

I am trying to update my local copy of project from the server and when I right click on the parent folder and select Update. I get this error.
*The xml response contains invalid xml*

On the server when I check the log i see this error
*Working copy path 'resources/hbm/City.hbm.xml' does not exist in repository [404, #160013]*

I am using TortoiseSVN 1.8.7, Build 25475 - 64 Bit and VisualSVN server Version: 2.7.7. Please help me to resolve this issue.
[image]
cheers
 Zolf

Comment: You get a "Commit Failed" message when you select "SVN Update"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. The error you get is about failed `svn commit` operation. It has nothing to do with `svn update`.
2. Most likely, the working copy is indeed out of date. I suggest checking out a clean working copy to different location and see whether you get the same errors. You won't get these errors, I guess.
3. If the new working copy is valid, then you can copy uncommitted changes from the old one and `svn commit` them succesfully to the repository.